# Removing an up vote to an answer

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes

Is it ok to remove an upvote to an answer if you later see a better answer, and now you just think the other answer does not measure up with the new answer you consider as the better one?

Comment: can we add this to the FAQ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can vote however you like.

Comment: However, you only have 5 minutes after your initial vote to change your mind - unless the answer is edited.

Comment: You could consider leaving the other vote though, if the answer is correct and you feel it deserves an upvote for its merit.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the 5 minute thing? Or to increase the time to one week?

Answer (score 4):

If you think the new answer is so much better that it should float to the top in the "votes" sorting order, then I'd say you have no other choice than to remove the upvote to the other correct answer. (*Downvoting* that other answer is clearly not an option.) So I say: Yes, it's OK if you remove that upvote.

<sup>(You can of course just use Juan's reasoning and vote however you like!)</sup>